# Is it possible for Shake to change a source file?

Tags: shake-build-system

When running tools such as formatters and linting tools with "auto-correction" options, it can be that the input and output for a `Rule` are the same file; for example:

```hs
  "//*.hs" %> \out ->
    cmd_ "ormolu" "-m" "inplace" out

-- OR

  batch 10 ("//*.hs" %>)
    ( \out -> do
      cmd_ "ormolu" "-m" "inplace" out
      pure out
    )
    (cmd_ "hlint")
```

This seems to work "correctly" (the rule is re-run if the source file is `need`ed and has changed), but we're unsure if this is a happy coincidence or `shake` working as designed - especially when we start thinking about cached results from `shakeShare` or in the future Cloud Shake. Is this the best way to handle this type of rule, or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no principled way to generate a rule that replaces a source file in Shake. Given a source code formatter, anything else isn't very usfeul. Shake makes the assumption that inputs don't change while the compilation is ongoing. It's likely that passing `--lint` will lead to a lint error and that it would be incompatible with Cloud Shake. The official advice would be to make such changes in a separate non-Shake pass before you call `shake`.

However, if it works for you, and is useful, I wouldn't overly worry. The pattern has tests in Shake, it's something plenty of people do. You can turn off Cloud caching on a per file basis with `historyDisable`.

Comment: Thanks @Neil Mitchell